# Take action after ui is fully loaded in Twilio flex plugin

Tags: twilio, twilio-flex

I need to perform an action in my twilio flex plugin after the ui is fully loaded. I could not find this in the flex docs, can someone help me? My idea here is to choose which activity to show to the worker based on the worker attributes, so i need the account menu to be completely loaded to remove some items after that.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this event inside the plugin:

`manager.events.addListener("pluginsInitialized", () => {});`